# Connecting to SQL Server failing intermittently with different different errors

Tags: .net, sql-server

We have an app which is hosted on an on-premise infrastructure. The app takes around 20 calls per sec. There are 40 servers on which the app is installed in a load balanced fashion. Each servers hosts other 8 to 10 app on a shared basis. Out of all apps only one app is having SQL Server connectivity issues. The connectivity issues is intermittent and appears with many different different error messages. The app is taking 20 calls per sec and each call in turn might make around 10 SQL Server connections and runs simple select and insert queries.

We checked SSL settings on client and server and there is no issue. No DB table locks are on the DB Server. We checked DB server, network and everything is fine. No memory or CPU issue on any of the server. No single issue is observed for any other app installed on the same application servers.

The code running SQL queries is pretty simple:

```
private List<values> GetItemsFromDB(string queryString, SqlParameter[] sqlParams)
{
    var listOfItems = new List<Item>();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_provider.ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var item = new Item()
                        {
                            Id = Convert.ToInt64(reader["Id"]),
                            SerializedConfigItem = reader["SerializedItem"] != DBNull.Value
                                ? reader["SerializedItem"].ToString()
                                : null,
                            SerializedItem2 = reader["SerializedItem2"] != DBNull.Value
                                ? reader["SerializedItem2"].ToString()
                                : null,
                            Created = reader["Created"] != DBNull.Value
                                ? Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Created"])
                                : DateTime.MinValue
                        };
                listOfItems.Add(item);
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logHandler.Error(ex.Message, "Error while trying to get items from DB");
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

        return listOfItems;
    }
}

private long WriteItemToDb(string queryString, SqlParameter[] sqlParams)
{
    long id = 0;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_provider.ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);

            var obj = command.ExecuteScalar();
            id = Convert.ToInt64(obj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logHandler.Error(ex.Message, "Error while trying to insert/update/delete items to DB");
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

        return id;
    }
}
```

Below are some of the different error messages we get randomly and intermittently:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup.)

> The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The handle is invalid.)

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The handle is invalid.)

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 9 - Associating port with I/O completion mechanism failed)

Comment: Is this app's connection string substantially different than the others? e.g.: does this app use an InstanceName while the others use specific ports?

Comment: These are all intermittent network errors. Very difficult to troubleshoot. It sounds like you have a complex load balancing setup there also although I can't grasp what it is from your description. In short I doubt if this is a SQL Server problem and is more likely network (or network in combination with something else)

Comment: Guessing this is a network fault, not a coding problem. Try in a command prompt `ping YourServer -t -w 100` and watch for drops. Might be a DNS issue, a broadcast storm (switch loop), faulty switch or router, bad cable, flapping routing.

Comment: We are using connection string as below: 
"Server=[fully qualified servername];Database=[db name];Integrated Security=SSPI;encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;Connection Timeout=180"
The same connection string is used for all other apps on the app servers. We engaged IT folks to see any network glitched but they did not see any network issues. Also i ruled out that possibility because if it is a network issue it should affect all other apps.

Comment: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred", "provider: TCP Provider, error". It's a network issue, related to something specific in SQL Server, and to your complex load balancing setup. Like maybe the load balancer switches hosts in the middle of a connection handshake or something.

Comment: So for 40 servers X 8 to 10 apps on each server, you have a total of say 390 instances of apps and only one of these apps in particular fails? Or one server? Or one type of app? Do all app types make SQL Server calls? Are the 8-10 apps the same app running in multiple services / instances or are they different apps? Why not just take the app out of the load balancing pool so it never gets called and you never get a failure? This issue is an intersection of many things, but you are getting network errors and you have a complex load balancing setup.